# bash trap will echo from keyboard Ctrl-C while not kill 2

Tags: bash, signals, bash-trap

Say I have a script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# test_trap.sh

trap "echo SIGINT captured!" SIGINT
echo $$

sleep 1000
```

I know trap COMMAND will only be executed after `sleep 1000` finishes when it receives SIGINT signal. But the command of trap will be executed when I pressed keyboard Ctrl-C:

```
> sh test_sh.sh
50138
^CSIGINT captured!
```

And using kill -s SIGINT will not.

What am I missing here?

The bash version is GNU bash, 4.2.46(2)-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `kill -s SIGINT 50138`, you are *only* sending the signal to the shell's process, and that has to wait for `sleep 1000` to finish, because `sleep` doesn't receive the signal.

Control-C, though, causes the terminal to send `SIGINT` to every process in the current process group, so both your shell script *and* `sleep` receive it. Your script still doesn't process the trap command until `sleep` completes, but `sleep` exits immediately in response to the `SIGINT` it just received from the terminal.

If your `kill` supports it, you can also use `kill -s SIGINT -50138` (note the negative process id) to send SIGINT to the entire process group.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation.